# Show selected option with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how to make next:
I want that when someone selects items from combobox, that item be shown in `div`.

What do I need to do?

```html
<body>
<h1>VEZBA STRUKTURA</h1>
<div id="prvi"></div>
 <select name="automobili" id="automobili">
  <option value="1">BMW</option>
  <option value="2">AUDI</option>
  <option value="3">OPEL</option>
  <option value="4">FERARI</option>
  <option value="5">SKODA</option>
  <option value="6">HJUNDAI</option> 
 </select>

<script>
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: E borise, borise sta ti ne znas :O

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Currently, there is no JS involved, even if you tagged your question with that. And reading the value of the selected option and put it into the div is not that hard...

Comment: e jbg,lako tako :D ajde ti pomozi,ja tek ucim

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach an event listener that executes when the value of the select changes:

```js
automobili.addEventListener('change', function() {
  prvi.innerHTML = automobili.selectedOptions[0].textContent
})
```

```html
<h1>VEZBA STRUKTURA</h1>
<div id="prvi"></div>
<select name="automobili" id="automobili">
  <option value="1">BMW</option>
  <option value="2">AUDI</option>
  <option value="3">OPEL</option>
  <option value="4">FERARI</option>
  <option value="5">SKODA</option>
  <option value="6">HJUNDAI</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: connexo thank you very much,big help for me beginer :)